# Remove leading or trailing spaces in an entire column of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I remove leading or trailing spaces of all cells in an entire column?

The worksheet's conventional `Find and Replace` (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) dialog is not solving the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify "Without code" ? Do you mean without vba just with formula's?

Comment: I don't know if the ribbonified Excel 2010 can still export to comma or tab separated value format, but if so, export it in one of those formats, modify in notepad (or whatever) and import it back.

Comment: without 'VBA' is great!!

Comment: Not sure why it was closed as off topic as its a legit question and Excel can be considered a functional programming language - his question was how to achieve the desired result given the set of Excel functions.

Comment: A useful link is this one http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/667-excel-remove-first-space.html

Comment: Be careful with these answers if you want to keep interior spaces between words. TRIM will remove ALL extra spaces, not just leading and trailing.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you would like to use a formula, the `TRIM` function will do exactly what you're looking for:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+
|    |     A      |           B         |
+----+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | =TRIM(B1)  |  value to trim here |
+----+------------+---------------------+
```

So to do the whole column...
1) Insert a column
2) Insert `TRIM` function pointed at cell you are trying to correct.
3) Copy formula down the page
4) Copy inserted column
5) Paste as "Values"

Should be good to go from there...

Comment: This `Trim` Doesn't worked out. still the resultant is getting with spaces

Comment: can you post an example of what didn't work out? Like a cell's worth of data that still has spaces after running the trim?

Comment: My guess is there are other characters then "spaces" in what you're trying to remove. You could try =TRIM(CLEAN(B1)) which will remove all non-printable characters and any leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Note that this solution will also delete consecutive embedded spaces - which might NOT be what you want, if you were hoping to just remove leading and trailing spaces!

Comment: trim will delete extra spaces in between words other than beginning and trailing spaces

Comment: I would not expect this, and there may be something I'm doing wrong - TRIM appears to be eliminating duplicated spaces in the middle of my string. Is there a way to only trim off leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: thanks. Trim worked eliminating the spaces at the end of my strings

Answer (score 234):

Quite often the issue is a **non-breaking space** - `CHAR(160)` - especially from Web text sources -that `CLEAN` can't remove, so I would go a step further than this and try a formula like this which replaces any non-breaking spaces with a standard one

`=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160)," ")))`

Ron de Bruin has an excellent post on [tips for cleaning data](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win017.htm) here

You can also remove the `CHAR(160)` directly without a workaround formula by

- *Edit .... Replace* your selected data,
- in *Find What* hold `ALT` and type `0160` using the numeric keypad
- Leave *Replace With* as blank and select *Replace All*

Answer (score 18):

Without using a formula you can do this with 'Text to columns'.

- Select the column that has the trailing spaces in the cells.
- Click 'Text to columns' from the 'Data' tab, then choose option 'Fixed width'.
- Set a break line so the longest text will fit. If your largest cell
  has 100 characters you can set the breakline on 200 or whatever you
  want.
- Finish the operation.
- You can now delete the new column Excel has created.

The 'side-effect' is that Excel has removed all trailing spaces in the original column.

Comment: this is really the simplest way to go. Thanks for the tip!
using TRIM() involves extra steps of adding a column and copy pasting values.

Comment: i like this answer better than Katherine's

Comment: This did NOT remove trailing spaces for me. Back to the new column/TRIM solution.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't higher up. So much faster than the formula method

Answer (score 7):

If it's the same number of characters at the beginning of the cell each time, you can use the text to columns command and select the fixed width option to chop the cell data into two columns.  Then just delete the unwanted stuff in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the best (and easiest) way to delete leading, trailing (and excessive) spaces in Excel is to use a third-party plugin. I've been using [ASAP Utilities for Excel](http://www.asap-utilities.com/) and it accomplishes the task as well as adds many other much-needed features.  This approach doesn't require writing formulas and can remove spaces on any selection spanning multiple columns and/or rows. I also use this to sanitize and remove the uninvited non-breaking space that often finds its way into Excel data when copying-and-pasting from other Microsoft products.

More information regarding ASAP Utilities and trimming can be found here:

http://www.asap-utilities.com/asap-utilities-excel-tools-tip.php?tip=87[image]

Answer (score -2):

I was able to use Find & Replace with the "Find what:" input field set to:

> " * "

*(space asterisk space with no double-quotes)*

and "Replace with:" set to:

> ""

*(nothing)*

Comment: i wasn't able to make this work. this needs regular expressions correct?