# How do I remove special " " spaces in excel columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I am using  Office 2003 under windows XP Pro

I copy and paste large lists from ms access 2003 database into excel daily so I can do various functions to the lists. The one problem I am having now is figuring out how to remove the spacial spaces (I thought it was called white space but it seems not the case) after the numbers or text.

```
example:

[1234     ]
[1234     ]
[1234     ]
[1234     ]
[34     ]
[12ABC     ]
```

(please note, the example above will work if you copy/paste. I was just giving example, visually.)

In excel, `=trim()` does not remove them. Also, (Search/Replace " " and leave empty) does not remove them. I have also tried a trick I use in other situation, copy/paste into notepad and then search/replace, did not remove them. That is why I called the term, special. But there is probably an actual term--I wouldn't mind knowing what its called, officially.

**I am not looking for a custom =function() in excel to run**.

This would not be practical to use in every day copy/paste since these are going directly into someone elses excel reports. I am adding my info to it and it gets processed further by others who are not excel savvy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060056/how-to-remove-a-single-leading-space-in-the-numeric-column-in-excel-2013/

Comment: Would a VBA Code help?

Comment: i searched google (advanced search page) and viewed many suggestions, (all were the same) but not resolved.  the issue is spacial.  i don't know the correct term for this..that's why i can't find.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Just notice that you are not looking for a VBA option.

Comment: Siddharth, no, it would not, because i am constantly copy/pasting between the two and things go rather quickly in my work.  i program in delphi, i could write something as well, but is not practical.  i need this to be an excel answer.  i believe the problem is a special "code" character to search for.  but i don't know what code ms access is placing in some of the data i copy from.  if i knew then i could search/replace by that.

Comment: Did you look at the link i Posted you have  non breaking spaces/CHAR(160) this is very common with data imports. Please review my answer To this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060056/how-to-remove-a-single-leading-space-in-the-numeric-column-in-excel-2013/16060772#16060772 or for how to do `Find and Replace` refer to Ole Henrik Skogstrøm's answer to the same question and to learn more you can look at this article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/remove-spaces-from-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-cell-HP003056131.aspx

Comment: appolgies..i'm at work..and interrupted a lot.

Comment: I appologize Ole Henrik Skogstrøm's answer was not on `Replace` but to remove in place. To `Replace` search for `ALT+0160`

Comment: i resolved it before i read user2140261 response. both methods work. but alt+0160 is quicker, thank you.  but in case anyone else needs to know.. in excel, bring up search/replace, press and hold the ALT key and while in the search box, enter 0160 (in numeric keypad, quickly ) and then release the ALT key, then leave the replace box empty and hit ok button.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove leading or trailing spaces in an entire column of excel worksheet in Excel2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/how-to-remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-excel-worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the =clean() function?  It removes many unusual characters.

Also you could use the =substitute() function if you know which specific ascii characters are being naughty.  They likely are #160's as suggested in the comments.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,char(160),"")
```

would work for that instance.

Hope that helps