# Remove line breaks, return carriages, and all leading space in Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have no idea what is happening, but I have cells that contain what appears to be a return carriage.  I have tried `TRIM()`, `CLEAN()`, `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")` and a number of macros to remove these characters.

The only way to remove these characters it to get the cell active, click delete near the last character, and click enter.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a way to programatically do this?

Comment: Have you seen [THIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219362/how-do-i-remove-special-spaces-in-excel-columns)

Comment: I did take a look at that, although the solutions to not resolve the issue

Comment: Did you try the Alt160 trick?

Comment: What is the code for the last character which you're having a problem deleting? You can loop through the characters and `debug.print` the codes for each one: that should help with an approach to removing them.

Comment: what Tim said. Sometimes the special characters look like something they are not, or even look like they are nothing at all. If you identify exactly what character(s) are offending, then you should be able to remove them!

Comment: Can you share a sample with us?

Comment: Is this for cells themselves and using `=clean(..)` wont work because it uses another cell?

Comment: Seen this> [How to remove leading or trailing spaces in an entire column of excel worksheet in Excel2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/how-to-remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-excel-worksheet)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following macro will remove all non-printable characters and beginning and ending spaces utilising the `Trim()` and `Clean()` functions:

```
Sub Clean_and_Trim_Cells()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim s As String
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        s = c.Value
        If Trim(Application.Clean(s)) <> s Then
            s = Trim(Application.Clean(s))
            c.Value = s
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution is find replace: for find press alt and the numbers 010 at the same time (on the 10 keypad) and then replace with a space.

You can do this as a bulk replace by just highlighting the cells that contain the carriage breaks.

Comment: I tried alt+10, which did not work.  Didn't know about alt+010, which worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

```
ws.Cells(i, j) = Replace(ws.Cells(i, j), Chr(13), "")
```

and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Select the entire column
  step 2: Press Cntrl+ H
  Step 3:
  Type'Cntrl+J' in the Find what box
  Step 4: Hit 'replace all'

Note: Cntrl+J here captures the carriage return cells.