# replacing carriage returns with a space (or any other chr) in vba?

Tags: vba

I was trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246078/remove-line-breaks-return-carriages-and-all-leading-space-in-excel-cell) for removing carriage returns but ran in to two problems:

1) returned an overflow error
2) his program only removed carriage returns, did not replace them.

I need to be able to replace carriage returns because currently, I have cells like this:

```
Apples
Oranges
Grapes
```

note, there is no "space" after each string. I need a space there in order to use the split() function. In the rest of my data sheet, I have cells that contain "Apples ", "Oranges ", "Grapes ". note the space after the string. These cells work very well with my program, it's the carriage returns that are giving me problems.

Comment: What about using the Replace function?  https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php

Comment: You should be able to Split on carriage returns, too.

Comment: Also, are they only carriage returns or carriage returns and a line feed?

Comment: @T_Bacon I thought that was the case but it looks like there are more characters. Do you have a list of all possible tabulation characters like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this simple statement?

```
myRange.Replace vbLf, " "
```

It works on a single cell as well as on a multiple range.

Comment: yeah this worked great! no clue why I didn't try it first.

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this:

```
items = Split(Replace(item, vbLf & vbCr, " "), " ")
```

Comment: I think the vblf alone might have been my problem. I was only filtering the carriage returns, I didn't know line feed existed. i'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: ok so it was working great until it got to a cell that contained "Ap " "Or" "Gr ". Is there any other character I could be missing? Thanks!