# How to remove blank spaces, vbLf, after and before the result of concatenation?

Tags: excel, vba

Input data in first image and result in second, column H.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Now read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/how-to-remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-excel-worksheet

Comment: Hi, Grijesh, the problem is delimiter that I use to concatenate cells: vbLf

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))," ",CHAR(10))
```

or VBA equivalent:

```
Sub test()
    With Range("D1:D10")
        .Replace Chr(10), " "
        .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(TRIM(" & .Address & "),)")
        .Replace " ", Chr(10)
        .WrapText = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method of concatenation that will avoid any unnecessary separators:

```
Public Function StitchValues(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant
    StitchValues = ""
    For Each r In rIn
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            If StitchValues = "" Then
                StitchValues = v
            Else
                StitchValues = StitchValues & vbLf & v
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

So in **H1** you would enter:

**=StitchValues(B1:E1)**

and then turn on text-wrapping, adjust row heights, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Gary,but a need vbLf delimiters, cause in my real sheet are telefone numbers.

Comment: The UDF inserts **vbLf** where they are needed, but not at the beginning or end of the concatenation.