# Debugging whitespace in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell in a table that reads:

`64123` where there is some sort of white space after 3.  I thought it was a blank space, so in my vba code, I've tried multiple ways of getting this blank space OUT of the string, but neither `application.trim` nor `replace` work.

```
With Cells(c.Row, 16)
  .NumberFormat = "General"
  v = Application.Trim(.Text)
  v = Replace(v, " ", "")
  Debug.Print v
  .Clear
  .NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = Application.Trim(v)
End With
```

There is definitely a blank space at the end - I can see it when I highlight the cell in Excel, and `Application.Trim` has ALWAYS worked for me.  What else could this be other than a blank space?  If it's a tab or a carriage return, what's the `replace` syntax for those?

Comment: lookup an ascii table and use the replace function with Chr(#) where # is the numerical value for tab or linefeed.

Comment: Awesome - thank you!  I got that the character is ascii # 149.  I'm not sure how to code that into a replace though

Comment: Replace(<yourString>,chr(149),"")

Comment: Why use `Application.Trim` when you can use `Trim`? (i.e. `VBA.Strings.Trim`)

Comment: my bad - I was actually setting the variable in excel to that, not determining what that character was.  When I set `v` - it's the 7th character in the string that is some type of white space.  I don't know how to determine WHAT character that 7th item in the string is.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, from my understanding there is a difference though not relevant here. Excel function trims all white spaces except single white spaces between words. VBA function only trims white spaces at the start or end of the string. Cheers.

Comment: `Debug.Print Asc(Right(Cells(c.Row, 16), 1))` What does this give you?

Comment: @nbayly, `trim` will trim spaces at both ends. `rtrim` and `ltrim` are the VBA functions to use if you only want to trim from a single end

Comment: @Sean Cheshire, agreed. My comment should have read "... start and/or end of the string". I was more pointing to the fact that the VBA will not trim 2 consecutive spaces into just 1 in between words inside the string, as the Excel function does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run this and it will tell you all the ascii values of your string

```
Sub tellMeWhatCharValues(h As String)
Dim i
    For i = 1 To Len(h)
        MsgBox Asc(Mid(h, i, 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

for just the 7th char

```
Sub tellMeWhatCharValues(h As String)
Dim i
    MsgBox Asc(Mid(h, 7, 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it does - so this worked, and you're my hero.  That's really nice code.  Freaking character 160!

Answer (score 4):

To add some points to Sorceri's answer:

There are a couple of variations of *space* characters that can make things more complicated, like [Thin Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space), [Zero Width Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), [Non-breaking Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), [and more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

`Trim` will not catch all of these (and probably shouldn't remove a *protected* space, #160).
Some of these are unicode-characters, that may return a question mark (ascii code 63) with `Asc`.
`AscW`/`ChrW` can be used for unicode characters (and work with ascii characters as well).

Try this:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "12345z" & Chr(160) & "x"
    Analyze s
    Debug.Print "---------"
    s = "12345z" & ChrW(8239) & "x" ' #8239 = narrow no-break space
    Analyze s
End Sub

Public Sub Analyze(s)
    Dim c As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        Debug.Print c & " => " & AscW(c)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Difficult blank spaces are often `CHAR(160)` as you found, see [Remove leading or trailing spaces in an entire column of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-data/9582919#9582919)

In your case you can remove them with code with

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace Chr(160), vbNullString
```

Comment: this is great as well!  I will definitely incorporate this into my logic.  I didn't realize I could use vbNullString as a replacement value.  sweet!