# Trimming spaces

Tags: excel, vba, trim

I'm trying to parse left and right empty spaces, nbsp, \n, \t, etc. from all Excel cells in a certain range.

I'm using the following macro:

```
Sub TRIM_CELLS()

    'Clean all conditional formating
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    'improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim all_cells_range As String
    all_cells_range = "A1:A10"

    'Trim all those cells
    Range(all_cells_range).Select
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        cell.Value = Application.Substitute(Application.Substitute(CStr(cell.Value), vbLf, vbCr), vbCr, "")
        cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim((Application.Clean(Replace(cell.Value, Chr(160), " "))))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Something like "Maria Tavares " doesn't get trimmed properly.

Comment: Try the solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/32617535/2570277

Answer (score 1):

I use a function that removes any special characters that you define.

```
Function RemoveSpecialCharacters(wks As Worksheet, strRange As String, var As Variant)
Dim rngAddress As Range, cell As Range, I&

'e.g strRange - "E2:E"

With wks
Set rngAddress = .Range(strRange & .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

  For I = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
    For Each cell In rngAddress
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, var(I), " ")
                Else
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, var(I), "")
    Next cell
  Next I
End With

End Function
```

You could call the function like this:

`RemoveSpecialCharacters worksheetname, "A1:A", Array(Chr(9), Chr(10), Chr(13), Chr(39))`

Where `Chr(10)` is linefeed character, `chr(9)` is the tab character etc.

See this [link](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm) for what other `Chr` codes stand for.

**UPDATE:**

Try this to remove the weird "spy" character from the cell.

`RemoveSpecialCharacters worksheetname, "A1:A", Array(Chr(160))`

Answer (score 1):

@Nick: I tried to use your idea and I think the problem is the char itself... Assuming the following loop works as expected I would get the char that is causing the problem.

Take a look at this image:

[image: "space is not a space"]

But nothing gets printed in that place.

```
Sub TRIM_CELLS()

    'Clean all conditional formating
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    'improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim all_cells_range As String
    all_cells_range = "A1:A2"

    'Trim all those cells
    Range(all_cells_range).Select
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        For I = 1 To 255
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, Chr(I), I)
        Next I

    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you get if you type this in the immediate window `len(trim(cell))` ?

Comment: The "weird char/space" gets accounted!

Comment: Try this. Convert the font in that cell to webdings. Type - not copy/paste - Maria Antonieta below it and also convert that to webdings. The rogue character should be visible at the end.What is it?

Comment: @Nick http://prntscr.com/pjl39z also did =code(cellWithOnlyWeirdChar) and the result was 160... but char(160) isn't converted

Comment: see the update in my answer. it think it's a `chr(160)`

Comment: not working :( cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, Chr(160), "----")

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a replacement with that "space"... not a great solution but fixed my problem... Just would like to know what char it was...

```
Sub TRIM_CELLS()

'Clean all conditional formating
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

'improve performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim all_cells_range As String
all_cells_range = "A1:A2"
Range(all_cells_range).Select
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    cell.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    cell.Value = Application.Substitute(Application.Substitute(CStr(cell.Value), vbLf, vbCr), vbCr, "")
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
Next cell

end sub
```