Weird hidden character in Excel that counts up in COUNTIF
I have an Excel sheet which is automatically created by an export of a time scheduler system. I want to count some columns content (to filter out all rows with no content). But weird: some cells appear to be empty (in the test file C2, H2 and I2) but with =COUNTIF(D2:BZ2;"<>") (german version: =ZÄHLENWENN(D2:BZ2;"<>")) they are considered as not empty. I can't figure out what the content is and how to skip it when counted.
Here is the testfile: http://tg11.de/COUNTIF-problem.xlsx
Do You have an idea how to handle this ominously pseudo empty cell as empty with COUNTIF without running a VBA script to tidy up?

What's the length of such a cell? Do you know ASCII values? (Or isn't it ASCII?) ...

Check the contents of the cells by writing =code([reference the cell[) across. You may have hidden characters.

=LENGTH(D2)is shown as 0. =CODE(D2)returns an error. ‍♂️

What about this thread? Any help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617535/excel-cell-has-an-invisible-character

@bdpolinsky Good idea, but still counted (and not applicable to a range for COUNTIF).

Maybe make use of the thrown error, like this: =COUNTA((FILTER(D2:BZ2,NOT(ISERROR(CODE(D2:BZ2))))))

Please try:
=COUNTA((FILTER(D2:BZ2,NOT(ISERROR(CODE(D2:BZ2))))))


Thank You so much. The idea is good.  However the formula has to be completed: The empty filter result is counted as 1 (even if it is replaced with "". Here is a functioning workaround: =IF(FILTER(D2:BZ2, NOT(ISERROR(CODE(D2:BZ2))), "x-x")="x-x", 0, COUNTA (FILTER(D2:BZ2, NOT(ISERROR(CODE(D2:BZ2))))))
