# VBA - String Manipulation empty spaces

Tags: string, vba

I am using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest to retrieve information from a site. 
However the retrieved information comes with some empty spaces before the beginning, which can be removed with LeftTrim function.

But even after the string is trimmed I still get some annoying things before the first letter.

```
Text before Ltrim
"     Hello World!"

Text after Ltrim
"  Hello World!"
```

Note: Using left to display the first char of the trimmed text returns "", but trying to use IF comparison to "" doesn't work so I can't get rid of these "".

```
If left("  Hello World!",1) = "" then 
   ' code to remove ""
```

How do I remove this damn things, what is this?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/9582919/2294676 - formula-based but could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly identify the rogue character - probably a tab:

```
str = trim$(str)

?"""" & str & """"
"   Hello World!"

'//what is the char code of the first char?
?ascw(left$(str, 1))
 9 '// tab
```

Then implement a custom `LTrim`, E.g.

```
Function LTrimWs(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Select Case Mid$(str, i, 1)
            Case " ", ChrW$(9)
               Mid$(str, i, 1) = " "
            Case Else
               LTrimWs = LTrim$(str)
               Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
Trim("    Hello World")
```

This will trim any blank spaces off the front and rear of the string.