# How can I remove ONLY leading and trailing spaces while leaving spaces in between words alone with an excel formula?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, whitespace

In excel, `TRIM()` will remove all spaces before and after text, while also removing any duplicate spaces in between words.

Is there a formula or combination thereof that will do the same as `TRIM()` but leave spaces between words as-is?

In the following example, I'm looking for a formula that will accomplish that of the fictitious formula "WXYZ":

`TRIM("  Omicron   Persei 8  ")` = `"Omicron Persei 8"`
`WXYZ("  Omicron   Persei 8  ")` = `"Omicron   Persei 8"`

Note that I've read somewhere that `TRIM()` in VBA will work like that of WXYZ above. However, I'm looking for a formula solution.

Comment: Very Good Question! If you don't want to use VB Script, it's pretty difficult. I can't think of anything. Just brainstormed and came up with trimming just the leading spaces. Would it work?

Comment: @ChaosLegion I have some spreadsheets that have values with spaces before and after the actual data. The cells from that sheet are referenced in a separate document. The issue is that once those cell values are put in a new document, they are compared to other cells. So leading and trailing spaces cause comparisons to fail. But the in between space cannot be removed because external software needs them to be there for further comparison.

Comment: I know that there are ways around using a formula solution. But since I couldn't find a formula, I thought I'd post it here to help out others in the same situation.

Comment: Are the spaces consistently the same, or are they differing lengths?

Comment: I mean you could always create the VBA trim as a user defined function `WXYZ` then use that as a formula

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-data), perhaps give it a quick read, theres a post referenceing a Ron De Bruin page about cleaning up data. It seems useful, I would have taken some time to apply it but I have a train to go catch.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - The leading and trailing spaces are of random lengths. The Q you linked to does not address my issue about keeping in between whitespace alone. The answers to that Q relate to using TRIM() (which I specifically can't use) and dealing with non-breaking spaces, which is not my issue.

Comment: in the comments they stated they needed the doubles in between.

Comment: didnt read further, sorry

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - Your idea of using a user defined VBA function isn't bad if working within the same document. I wanted a pure formula solution though, so that other users who don't fully understand formulas or VBA can just copy and paste the formula into different documents without being confused.

Comment: If you are, like I was, looking for a way to remove only the leading spaces (using an Excel formula) then I've created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75377850/an-excel-formula-for-remove-only-leading-spaces-in-a-cell/75377964#75377964 and it borrows from @aakash answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the answer posted by @JvdV. It removed leading and trailing spaces from a value that had spaces in the middle to begin with and preserved all middle spaces (which is great).

But, for a value with no spaces in the middle to begin with, the formula returned an error. So, I added to it. I took the formula from @JvdV and put it inside an IF() that tests for the presence of middle spaces. If there are middle spaces, it runs the formula, but if not, it simply runs TRIM().

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",TRIM(A2))), LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ",,1),TEXTJOIN(DROP(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(" "&A2&" ",x),,1),,-1),,x)), TRIM(A2))
```

Comment: Good catch! Your formula takes the crown.

Comment: Yeah nice catch. You can also use `=IFERROR(<OriginalFormula>,TRIM(A2))` btw.

Comment: @JvdV Nice, the IFERROR version worked for me as well. Btw I was going to just add a comment to your answer, but I didn’t have enough reputation to do that. Working on building some now 

Comment: @MattLeonard FYI it's generally preferrable to post things like that (new answers/solutions) as their own answers. That way they are treated the same (with up and down votes), editing, etc. Comments work much differently.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should work (assuming your string is located at A1):

`=MID(A1,
  FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1),
  (LEN(A1)-MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),INDEX(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1),0),0)-FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)+2)`

`FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)` returns the location of the first non-space character in the string

`MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),INDEX(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1),0),0)` returns the location of the last non-space character in the string **from right-to-left**.

Comment: I tried your answer right after you posted it and it appears to work. But then SE said your answer was edited. But I don't see anything about your answer being edited anymore...did you change anything?

Comment: Just added the assumption of the string being located at A1 (no change to formula).

Comment: It's not pretty, but it does the job. I'll accept this if no one has a better solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

How would this look in Excel 365? A bit easier I think with let, sequence and xmatch but not particularly short:

```
=IFERROR(LET(seq,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),
array,MID(A2,seq,1),
start,XMATCH(TRUE,array<>" "),
finish,XMATCH(TRUE,array<>" ",0,-1),
MID(A2,start,finish-start+1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Confirmed working!

Comment: Just for fun, since this question is tagged somewhere else I came across your post. I came up with `=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ",,1),TEXTJOIN(DROP(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(" "&A2&" ",x),,1),,-1),,x))`

Comment: @JvdV Your formula also works! Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to all the valuable content:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ",,1),TEXTJOIN(DROP(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(" "&A2&" ",x),,1),,-1),,x))
```

Comment: I have changed this to the accepted answer. It's much shorter than the other solutions and I wasn't able to find any inputs that cause a deviation in output from the other ones.

Comment: This formula returns an error if there is no space in the middle of the value. Matt Leonard posted a fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

A Formula Array could also be used.

Assuming the string is located at `A1` enter this *Formula Array* in `B2`. It's highly suggested to ensure this part of the formula `ROW(B:B)` refers always to the same column were the formula is located (column `B` in this case), this is in order to avoid the formula returning an error if the column to which it refers is deleted.

```
=MID($A1,
FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1),
1+MAX(ROW(B:B)*(ROW(B:B)<=LEN($A1))*(MID($A1,ROW(B:B),1)<>" "))
-FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1))
```

*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

As regards the formula provided by @Aakash I suggest to replace the `INDIRECT` function in this part:

```
-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A7)))
```

with this:

```
-ROW(B:B)
```

So the formula will become *Non-Volatile*:

```
=MID($A1,
FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1),
(LEN($A1)-MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM($A1),1),INDEX(MID($A1,LEN($A1)-ROW(B:B)+1,1),0),0)
-FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1)+2))
```